# Django- Can I Display Data in My Apps Detailview from a Model Connected to My App

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have 3 apps in my Django (1.11) project:

My  ***journal*** app has a `Journal` model with a `ForeignKey` field connected to my ***rate*** app. My ***product*** app is also connected to the ***rate*** app by a `ForeignKey` extending from the `Product` model.

Here is the code for the three models:

```
# journal app
class Journal(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
      ...

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

# product app
class Product(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
      ...

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

# rate app
from journal.models import Journal
from product.models import Product


class Frequency(models.Model):
      frequency = models.CharField(max_length=20)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.frequency

class Rate(models.Model):
      price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
      frequency = models.ForeignKey(Frequency)
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
      journal = models.ForeignKey(Journal)

      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.price)
```

I can define a `price` in the `Rate` model based on the `Product.name`, `Journal.name`, and the `Frequency.frequency`. Since the ***rate*** app allows me to set the price for each **product** based on the **frequency** and **journal**, I want to display that information back in my ***journal*** app within my template being rendered by this view:

```
class JournalDetailView(DetailView):
      context_object_name = 'journal'
      model = Journal
      queryset = Journal.objects.all()
      template_name = 'journal_detail.html'
```

This way all journal-specific information in `journal_detail.html`

MY QUESTION: 
Is accessing the rate data that is unique to a specific product and journal something I can access back inside by ***journal*** app? I know adding another ForeignKey from `Rate` to `Journal` will throw an error but I cannot think of any other logic to accomplish this task.

Comment: Just an observation: you don't need to define both `model` and `queryset` in your `DetailView`; one is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then what you want should be possible.

```
class JournalDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'journal'
    model = Journal
    template_name = 'journal_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # rates related to the current journal
        ctx['rates_list_1'] = self.object.rate_set.all()

        # rates related to the current journal and a specific product
        # that has been past to the request as an query string parameter
        some_product = get_object_or_404(
            Product, pk=self.request.GET.get('product_id'))
        ctx['rates_list_2'] = self.object.rate_set.filter(product=some_product)

        return ctx
```

This code sample takes advantage of the [`get_context_data` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data) to add variables to your template context.

Comment: `some_product` should be an `Product` instance; Maybe you could use `Product.objects.get(pk=1)` or `get_object_or_404(Product, pk=1)` or something similar to get the instance of which you want to get the rates.

Comment: Thanks, @Ralf! I was able to get the **frequency, price**, and **journal** from rate.Rate in the DetailView using the rate_list_1 ctx. I understand using get_context_data for the ***ctx['rate_list_1'] = self.object.rate_set.all()***.  However, I am curious to see an example of the type of logic needed set ***some_product =*** to. I wasn't able to find an example where the variable is dynamic based on the data selected vs a variable that is hard coded. i.e.***some_product = Product.object.filter(id=1)***.  This is primarily why I was not able to make the second context dict work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Updated my answer: you could pass the `product_id` as a query string parameter to the request.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to import the Product and Rate models into your Journal app and then filter the Products by their relation to a Journal, then find the associated Rate object?

Comment: Hi @Alister, thanks for the input - I did think about that approach, however, each product has 6 different rates based on the ***Frequency*** model so it ends up being less expensive and confusing on the admin side to make the connection in the Rate app.